# Sock Drawer removal probability

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I have 30 socks in my drawer, and they vary in colour, I have 12 Black, 10 Blue, 2 Brown, and 6 grey socks. If I close my eyes and pull socks out at random, how many socks must I pull out before I can be certain to have a matching pair? I know there are similar questions but I need to know the method in how you obtain the answer or formula if that is what is required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "how many socks **must** I pull out before I am **guaranteed** (*with 100% probability*) to have a matching pair" is a different question than "how many socks must I pull out before I have *at least an $x\%$ chance* of having a matching pair" or "what is the *expected number* of socks needed to pull out to have a matching pair."  The first phrasing seems to match your question closest and is just an application of the pigeon-hole principle and has very little to do with probability.

Comment: @JMoravitz agreed. OP uses "must" and "certain".

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've described actually isn't probability but an application of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle):

In worst case, you pull out one of each color, so the 5th sock much match one of the others.

Comment: So what if I pull out 2 Black socks straight away, then 2 Blue and 2 Grey? and still not have a pair, or am I missing the point?

Comment: @roger OK, I was under the impression that socks of a color were indistinguishable - that is any 2 black socks pulled out form a pair.

Comment: @roger usually in these "socks" and "pairs" problems, all black socks are treated as identical and all grey socks are treated as identical, etc...  Any two socks of the same color can act as a pair, unlike shoes which have a right-shoe and a left-shoe.